# search on dropdownlist items

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I am creating dropdownlist in edit template of gridview, and I want to implement progressive search on  dropdown item.  Which means if i press 'm' it shows items starts with 'm' then if I press 'o' it will show items start with 'o'.  Instead of this, I want items containing 'mo'.

I am using asp.net,c# 2.0

Comment: Are you using Asp.NET 2?  or C# 2.0  ?  And please give some code examples.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want autocomplete.  Check out this [ajax toolkit example](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx).  Ajax Toolkit provides you with a built in custom control that does exactly what you are looking for, the link I posted should have all that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article this was done by using a text box to search change acording to your requirements

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/205_Searching_Inside_the_GridView_Control.aspx